# Excel MATCH to sum of two cell values

Tags: excel

I have a table of data that include a name column and two numeric columns.  Example:

```
  A      B   C
Fred     4   2
Sam      3   6
George   1   7
```

I'm wanting to retrieve the name in column A for the largest sum of columns B and C.  In the example above, I would want "Sam" because 3+6 is greater than any of the other sums.

I know I could create a hidden column (D) that's filed with

```
=SUM(B2,C2)
```

and do something like this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(D:D),D:D,0))
```

but I'd rather avoid the hidden column, if possible.  Is there a way to perform an index-match based on the sum of two cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **array formula**:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX((B:B)+(C:C)),(B:B)+(C:C),0))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

*(Note the appearance of braces in the formula bar)*

Comment: Believe it or not, I had tried this and it didn't work for me.  But I figured out why.  My first row has labels, so the addition was erroring out for the string values.  I changed the formula to A2:A50 (for example) and added +1 to the row number within the INDEX function and it worked like a charm.  Thanks, @Gary's Student.